# Excel formula vlookup with if and match not working

Tags: match, vlookup

Having a lot of difficulty with this example.

Goal is to vlookup by opportunity name in column I, that matches same in Column A and with Column D matching respective columns M through S, to enter the exact date from column H. Column A has multiple entries for same opportunity name.[sample excel file i'm working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5OXd.png)

Sample: Opportunity 1406 has a "Prospecting" Date of 2/12/14 and a "Closed - Lost (Cold)" Date of 2/12/14, the others are blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Index(Match())  Function would work very well in this scenario.  You can have multiple criteria .  Have a look at this [index match example](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2012/07/12/check-multiple-criteria-with-excel-index-and-match/)

If this helps, please mark as answered.

thanks